# Platform independent way of setting a unhandled exception handler using Qt?

Tags: windows, macos, qt

Mac OS X (Cocoa)
NSSetUncaughtExceptionHandler

Windows
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter

Is there a platform independent way to do this using Qt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about obvious handler in main()?
I mean your application have following lines:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow mainWin;
    mainWin.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

What about simple wrap it with:

```
try{
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   ...
}
catch //catches any previously unhandled
{
    //do graceful exit
}
```

Comment: This isn't the same semantics at least on Windows, as it won't catch SEH exceptions

Comment: i'm afraid this is the only portable way.

Answer (score 1):

Would it really be so bad to have to write #ifdefs around this? It's just a single instance and you'll never have to look at it again once you finish it. That being said at least on Windows, I'd encourage you to *not* do this, and instead register for Vista+'s Restart Manager if it's available.

Comment: it is not so bad. as a matter of fact, i've already done so. just wanna check whether i have missed a cleaner way of doing this.